# PHP class use other classes from composer

Tags: php, composer-php, php-telegram-bot

I made a class which autoloads with psr-4.
In this class I wanted to use classes from some libraries that I downloaded with composer the problem is that I can't seem to figure it out.
Class:

```
<?php
namespace CusTelegram\CusCommand; 
use Telegram\Bot\Actions;
use Telegram\Bot\Commands\Command;
class NewEpisodeCommand extends Command
{
    public function handle($arguments)
    { 
        ...
        $dotenv = new Dotenv\Dotenv(__DIR__ . "/../..");
        $this->replyWithMessage(['text' => __DIR__ . "/../.."]);
        $dotenv->overload();
        $client = new ApiVideo\Client\Client($_ENV["API_EMAIL"], $_ENV["API_KEY"]);
        ...
}
```

The method handle gets called from a telegram webhook so I don't know how to degub it but I'm 100% sure that it crashes when Dotenv tries to get instanciated.
Tree view:

```
/CusTelegram
  /CusCommand
    /NewEpisodeCommand.php (this class)
/bot
  /bot.php
/vendor
...
```

In bot php I already require the autoload. This class doesn't have issues is just that I can't use DotEnv and ApiVideo in the NewEpisodeCommand class.
Bot.php:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';

use Telegram\Bot\Api;
$telegram = new Api(<token>);
$commands = [CusTelegram\CusCommand\StartCommand::class, CusTelegram\CusCommand\NewEpisodeCommand::class, Telegram\Bot\Commands\HelpCommand::class ];
$telegram->addCommands($commands);

$update = $telegram->commandsHandler(true);
```

**--EDIT--**
I was able to print the error and this is what I get:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'CusTelegram\CusCommand\Dotenv\Dotenv' not found in /membri/streamapi/CusTelegram/CusCommand/NewEpisodeCommand.php
```

Comment: I can't see the problem beacuse it gets called from the telegram api since it is in a webhook and on my hosting I can't access the error log folder

Comment: We won’t be able to help you if you can’t tell us the error. Consider writing tests for it, and finding a way of testing it locally.

Comment: Is there any way to log the error on the folder that I'm on? I tried every method and It doesn't work.

Comment: I was able to print the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the error I just needed to insert the use path like:

```
use Dotenv\Dotenv;
use ApiVideo\Client\Client;
```

Comment: If you didn't want to use the `use` statement, you would have to prefix the FQCN with a backslash like this: `$dotenv = new \Dotenv\Dotenv(__DIR__ . "/../..");`